# Python Redis interaction

Tags: python, redis

I want to write application in python which uses redis. I googled but I could not find any results for my question. Usually, I do this:

```
import redis

rs = redis.Redis('localhost')
```

then do all gets and sets. But can I in redis do something like this:

```
rs1 = redis.Redis('app1')
rs2 = redis.Redis('app2')
```

I mean, I want to use two or more instances, each of which stores different things (for example rs1 for urls, rs2 for headers, etc...).
And also I want to know how to delete all keys (for example in rs1 delete all records). 
Any good tutorial, resource? 
Note: I need to use redis because I need to preform fast check and store, like url-seen for crawler.

Comment: Read http://redis.io. It has comprehensive documentation for all redis commands.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As showed in the [getting started section of the docs](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#getting-started) `redis.Redis` and `redis.StrictRedis` both take an integer `db` argument as a constructor parameter. That will get you an effectively silo'ed instance.

You could do something like the following:

```
rs1 = redis.Redis(host="localhost", db=0)
rs2 = redis.Redis(host="localhost", db=1)
```

`flushdb()` will clear all the keys for the database you are connected to, while `flushall()` will clear all the keys for every database.

Comment: Actually, flushall will clear all keys in all DBS. Flushdb is for flushing the db you are connected to. The flushall demonstrates that the DBS are not siloed.